# How to get clicked coordinates of a View when performClick() is used for accessibility purposes?

Tags: java, android

I have a custom view which shows a dartboard. It overrides the `onTouchEvent` method. For improving the accessibility of the app I wanted to override the `performClick` method too and call it from within the `onTouchEvent`. So far it seems pretty obvious.

My problem is that the `performClick` method has no access to the clicked coordinates. But I need those to draw the darts on the dartboard at the clicked positions. Is there a way to accomplish this or is this a restriction of accessibility implementations?

Here is what I am referring to in code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            saveDartPosition(event.getX(), event.getY());  // SHOULD BE IN performClick
            performClick();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    super.performClick();
    // NO WAY TO ACCESS COORDINATES HERE :-(
    return true;
}
```